# Graph with 5 vertices - # of spanning trees

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

If a graph has 5 vertices, all of them connected to each other vertex, how many different spanning trees exist?

I'm thinking the answer might be $4*3*2$, because the first point has 4 options to go to, the next vertex has three options, etc.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula

Answer (score 1):

We have $5$ trees with a node of degree four (choose the one node with degree four).
We have $5\cdot 4\cdot3$ trees with one node of degree three and one of degree two (choose one node with degree three, choose one of the remaining nodes to have degree two, then choose the other neighboour of this node).
We have $\frac{5!}2$ trees that are linear (i.e. have three nodes of degree two) (choose an arbitrary order and observe that backwards order gives the same line/tree as forward).
In total, that's $125$, I guess (at least after adjusting the cont according to polkjh's comment).

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure I understand fully.

Comment: Number of trees with one node of degree $3$ and one of degree $2$ is $5.4.3$ (picking nodes of degrees $3$ and $2$ and picking which node is connected to degree $2$ node). This makes it a total of $125$ ($=5^3$ as expected from Cayley's formula)

Comment: @polkjh Ah, right, missed that.